# How to make NuGet package published on GitHub available to all repositories in organization automatically?

Tags: c#, github, nuget

I have successfully managed to publish a NuGet package using a GitHub Actions workflow, to our NuGet package repository on GitHub.

I can add the package locally to an application project, but when I push the application project to its GitHub repository, build actions for that repository fails to build the application, as it cannot locate the NuGet package.

Here's what I did:

- I can add the package locally, from our NuGet repository, which has a link like this: `https://nuget.pkg.github.com/ORGANIZATION_SLUG/index.json`, and this works for me locally.
- I thus added the published NuGet package as a dependency to the application project, built, and pushed my change to NuGet. It failed to build, saying it cannot find the NuGet package.
- I added the GitHub repository as a NuGet source in the workflow for that other project like this:

  ```bash
  dotnet nuget add source --username USERNAME --password "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
      --store-password-in-clear-text --name Github
      "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/ORGANIZATION_SLUG/index.json"
  ```

  Except for the `ORGANIZATION_SLUG` part and the fact that I broke the line over multiple lines above, for readability, the rest is verbatim, exactly like I have it in my workflow file. That whole thing is one long line in my workflow file.

  This did not work either, still cannot locate the package.
- However, I then navigated to the repository with the NuGet package, clicked my way to the settings for that package, and listed the repository for the application project under "Manage Actions Access".

  Now the application builds using a workflow action.

Is it possible for me to configure the repositories, or our GitHub organization, in such a way that I don't have to manually list all repositories that will use the NuGet package? We plan on using a lot of NuGet packages internally, and it would be better if this just worked without having to manually add dependent projects every time.